# Ember 2.x How to do linked dropdowns with data sourced from server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't seem to find my first foothold on this. I found some older 1.x ways of kinda of doing what I want, but always from hard coded arrays.

Simply stated, I want a States drop down which gets its data from my server. When the user selects the state I need the Counties drop down to fetch the list of counties in that state from my server.

Pretty easy with straight Ajax and JS but learning the Ember 2.x way of doing it has proven elusive.

Are there any git projects, jsbins, twiddles or such that demonstrate the techniques needed to do this? Or someone adventurous enough to do a tutorial on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [example](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/custom-search-action) from official guide of [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select). The example fetches data from github repositories and its usage is pretty simple.

Regarding the answer you have provided I would suggest the following changes:

js file is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  company: null,
  router: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  countyNames: Ember.computed('company.state', function() {
    return this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + state).then((json) => json.map((county)=> {
      return county.name;
    });
  }),

  states: ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'],

  actions: {
    // For dropdown handling
    chooseState(state) {
      this.set('company.state', state);
    },

    chooseCounty(countyName) {
      this.set('company.county', countyName);
    }
});
```

The template is:

```
  {{#power-select
    selected=company.state
    options=states
    onchange=(action "chooseState")
    as |name|
  }}
    {{name}}
  {{/power-select}}

  {{#power-select
    selected=company.county
    options=countyNames
    onchange=(action "chooseCounty")
    as |name|
  }}
    {{name}}
  {{/power-select}}
```

The problem with the answer you have provided is that; you are providing a selected for county dropdown which is string (`company.county`); however your `options` for counties are json objects. Hence; the second dropdown is empty when you select it. Yet, in order the initial values for the second dropdown to appear you need to fetch the county names for the initial selected state. In order to overcome these two problems I defined `countyNames` computed property that will be the options for county dropdown. It depends on `company.state`; hence whenever the state of the company changes it will be recalculated. I also defined it to contain only the names of the counties so that selected value for dropdown will appear when you make a selection. Note that there should be some typos in code snippets I have provided because I did not try it; but I hope it will be enough for you to understand my point. Best regards.

Comment: That does it! I tweaked the syntax of the countyNames property (and edited your post to reflect that) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @alptugd for pointing me in the right direction. Here is what I did, though see below, I need some help refining it:

Installed [ember-power-select](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select)

In my component (where the drop down will reside) I put two drop downs, one for states and one for counties (note that company is my model here):

```
  {{#power-select
    selected=company.state
    options=states
    onchange=(action "chooseState")
    as |name|
  }}
    {{name}}
  {{/power-select}}

  {{#power-select
    selected=company.county
    options=counties
    onchange=(action "chooseCounty")
    as |name|
  }}
    {{name.countyName}}
  {{/power-select}}
```

The in the component's js file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from '../../config/environment';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  company: null,
  router: Ember.inject.service('-routing'),

  ajax: Ember.inject.service(),
  counties: [],

  states: ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME', 'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY'],

  actions: {
    // For dropdown handling
    chooseState(state) {
      this.set('company.state', state);
      //Ember.set(this, "counties", this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + state).then((json) => json.items));
      this.set('counties', this.get('ajax').request(config.host + '/api/counties/' + state).then((json) => json));
    },

    chooseCounty(county) {
      this.set('company.county', county.countyName);
    }
});
```

Now let me explain a bit about what's happening.

When the state drop down is changed, the `chooseState` action is called (`onchange=(action "chooseState")`) which sets the model's company.state value and then uses Ajax to get the counties in that state and assign the results to the component's counties variable. The counties drop down is getting its values from this counties variable ('options=counties') and will automatically render with the new values.

Now in my case, the API is passing back an array of objects. This means I need to specify which value to display in the drop down and I do that in the template with this line: `{{name.countyName}}` If you were just getting a list of string you could just do: `{{name}}`. I also need to pass back the right value to the model and I do that in the `chooseCounty` action.

This works, with two problems I hope others can help me dial in.

First, for some reason when you select the county, the drop down stays blank. The action is called and the model updated so when you save the record your database is all fine.

Second, I do not know where to first populate the county drop down. I need to do this after the model has been loaded so we know what state we are in.

Comment: I have updated my answer; hope it will help you. Please do not forget to upvote helpful answers and accept the ones that solves your question.